# Angular - how to display text / String / Date type based on the mat select drop down

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-ui

Based on Mat-select selected value (text/Number/Date) text field type and relevant element have to be shown. Here is my code but in this code, I am showing all.

For example
If user selecting drop down as date only date field has to show not string/ number vice versa for others.....

```
          <form class="example-form">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Name of Assumption </mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Assumption Name">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Selected Assumption Type...</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControl="dataType">
                        <mat-option value="Number">Number</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="Text">Text</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="Date">Date</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Contracted Value </mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Assumption Value">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Contracted Value </mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Assumption Value">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Contracted Value </mat-label>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-field>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Description (Optional) </mat-label>
                <textarea matInput></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </form>
```

Please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: can you explain what you want ?

Comment: @NavruzbekNoraliev thanks for replying based on drop down value that particular element only has to show for example if user selecting date only date has to display not string / Number if user selecting string that particular field has to display not others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it in a very simple way using ngIf conditional and #selector pls note other mat-form-fields continue in the same way...
here is your code

```
<form class="example-form">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Name of Assumption </mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Assumption Name">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Selected Assumption Type...</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControl="dataType" #selectVal>
                        <mat-option value="Number">Number</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="Text">Text</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="Date">Date</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="selectVal.value == 'Text'">
                <mat-label>Contracted Value </mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Assumption Value">
            </mat-form-field>


            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Description (Optional) </mat-label>
                <textarea matInput></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </form>
```

Comment: thanks for your help i was trying like this  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="selectVal.value == 'Text'"> 
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="selectVal.value == 'Number'">

 but I am getting error as 

Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: I am getting the value error here

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="selectVal.value == 'Date'">
            <mat-label>Contracted Value </mat-label>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
        </mat-form-field>

Comment: did you put #selectVal in select tag ?

Comment: thaaanks ))))))